# AG Grid Angular- First row getting disappear when resizing with drag column header in browser

Tags: ag-grid-angular

While working on my project, I found a strange issue that, AG-grid data getting populated while loading the page in browser. But while resizing any column header width manually in browser, first row of the table temporarily hidden, and again If i do a scroll-up and down, or sort ascending or descending the first row again appears.
here is the screenshot :
[image: Initial loading]
[image: After dragging column header in browser]

But I can see data is there in network tab while checking in debugger.

Can anyone please help me, where is the exact issue actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved adding key column to it programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

This might be because of CSS transform property on each row. Try adding:

```
suppressRowTransform=true
```

To use CSS top property instead.

https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/row-spanning/#configuring-row-spanning